# remove \n from a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following 2D array which is created from reading a file

`[['1', '200', '312', '4321', '53123\n'], ['2', '234', '313', '4342', '55657\n'], ['3', '343', '454', '587\n']]`

it is created using the following

```
def returnDocument(PROFILE):
    with open("tbs_save.txt") as textFile:
        data = [data.split(",") for data in textFile]
    print(data)
```

the data is stored like this

```
1,200,312,4321,53123
2,234,313,4342,55657
3,343,454,587
```

how can i remove the \n from the end of each array?

Comment: Maybe you can make use of this while fetching data and making list:
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip

Comment: it would but the data is stored on a separate file with each list on a new line

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `strip()` for each line of the text file to remove the trailing '\n'.

```
data = [data.strip().split(",") for data in textFile]
```

Alternatively, since your file contains integers, you could convert each entry to an integer in the list comprehension. Integer conversion will get rid of the '\n' as well.

```
data = [list(map(int, data.split(","))) for data in textFile]
```

Comment: it returns an empty array? (like this: [ ])

Comment: oh wait no it worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you works with the csv-files, so you can use the `csv.reader` to work with the data in a more convenient way. For example:

```py
import csv

def return_document():
    with open("tbs_save.txt") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
        data = [row for row in reader]
    print(data)
```

For the provided data example, to output will be:

```
[['1', '200', '312', '4321', '53123'], ['2', '234', '313', '4342', '55657'], ['3', '343', '454', '587']]
```

Also, the `csv.reader` usage allows you to avoid some bugs, for example in case when somebody will put spaces after commas in some files

Comment: It's recommended to open the file with `newline=''`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu It is not necessary for this case, actually